# Using pandas to concatenate strings of multiple row by column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want use the first 5 rows of my data frame and concentrate the string to form a new index.

Doing some research i think groupby with agg and lambda will work. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I am new to python.

For example my current data frame:

Dataframe (df):

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | fixed | variable | electric |  |  |
|  | Cost | Cost | Power | Max | Min |
| receipt | Unit | Unit | Another header | Rate | Rate |
| delivery zone | Rate | Rate | Rate | 1 | 1/2 |
|  | $ | $ | $ | $ | $ |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Desired Outcome:

| receipt delivery zone | fixed cost unit rate | variable cost unit rate | electric Power Another header Rate | Max Rate | Min Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use `.groupby()` or `lambda`. Simply use `.agg(sum)` on the first n-th rows to get concatenate the strings.

first step, get the slice:

```
slc = df.iloc[:4,:]
```

use `.agg(sum)` to aggregate the strings in one row.

```
new_cols = slc.agg(sum)
```

Simply reassign the column names

```
df.columns = new_cols
```